# How to exclude a set of numbers from a master column

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I exclude a set of numbers from a column?

For example:

Column A has the following set of numbers:

```
001440
001445
001448
001454
001512
001593
001688
001748
001758
001789
001837
001973
001977
002200
002202
```

Column B has the following set of numbers:

```
001748
001454
001688
```

How can I quickly find and exclude column B numbers from Column A? I'm dealing with thousands of rows of numbers so what would be the appropriate formula to use? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by exclude them?  Exclude them how?  What would be the output?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by exclude?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or some VBA? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'd like to remove the numbers listed in Column B from Column A. The output would be Column B's numbers filtered from Column A. I'd like to do this with a formula if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `VLOOKUP()` and a filter.

Insert a column between the two.  Then use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$C$4,1,FALSE),"")`. Then highlight just columns A & B, and filter column B to show only BLANK:

[image]

Now you can copy to a new sheet, pasting as values. (Or do whatever).  Note that you can't technically *remove* a value with formulas. For that, you'd need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in column C

> =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),B1,"")

Comment: I think you have these backwards - do you mean `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")`?